# using preg_match_all for nested brackets

Tags: php, pcre, preg-match-all

I have a string like this:

This is a {{text}} for {{testing}} PHP {{regular expression}}

I use the following pattern to get an array containing {{text}} , {{testing}} , {{regular expression}}

```
/\{\{.+\}\}/
```

But it returns an array with only 1 element:

"{{text}} for {{testing}} php {{regular expression}}"

Also tried this one:

```
/\{\{(?R)|.+\}\}/
```

But I get the same result.

What's wrong with this pattern?

Thanks.

Comment: `'/\{.*?\}/i'` , why are you trying to match double brackets ? try my regex out and tell us if you get the desired result .

Comment: @poelinca: Sorry for mistake.Edited!

Comment: `'/\{\{.*?\}\}/i'` should work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `/\{\{.+?\}\}/`, notice the ?, the original is greedy, that means it will match as many characters as it can, and if you have .+ it means it will go from the first { to the last }.

The `+?`, `*?` are the non-greedy versions of `+` and `*`.

Answer (score 0):

I think faster solution would be the regex `/\{\{([^}]+)\}\}/`, because non-greedy quantifier gets letter by letter until it reach right bracket while this regex eats everything up to right bracket on first try.

EDIT

additionally, I think the OP want to work with matched result, so added matching parentheses around `[^}]+`.